# 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'

Tags: ios, ios7, nsmutablestring

Im inserting a string into a NSMutableString like as

```
NSMutableString *string = (NSMutableString *)self.label.text;
[string insertString:@"New " atIndex:0];
```

these line of codes working properly iOS 6 device. but in iOS 7 it throws an exception as `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'` (i'm running ios 6 app in ios 7 device).

can any body tell why it's happening? please.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert an `NSString` to an `NSMutableString` simply by casting. Do this instead:

```
NSMutableString *string = [self.label.text mutableCopy];
```

Comment: thanks, it's working. But one doubt, how it is working in ios 6 and not in ios 7?. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how your code ever worked. It should have caused problems since iOS 2.0.